# IBInspectable with Cocoa Touch Framework not working? (code attached)

Tags: xcode8, ios10, ibdesignable, ibinspectable, cocoa-touch

I can not seem to get the "titleText" IBInspectable attribute working.  I have a simple framework view with a UILabel which I create an IBInspectable variable "titleText".  I note the inspectable "layer" variables work as expected, but not my custom "titleText" which is supposed to update the main view using this framework.

Issues are:

1. Interface Builder not updating the titleLabel? (i.e. at design time)  i.e. I'm expecting that this should, just like it is working for the "layer" items.
2. At Run Time the value of titleLabel is not picking up the value I set in IB either.  Note that I get the following output when I run, i.e. my code that produces this is finding the "self.titleLabel" is actually nil??

CODE SUMMARY

[image]

(a) gcCustomView.xib Snapshot
[image]

(b) gcCustomerView.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable 
class gcCustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBInspectable var titleText: String = "Default" {
        didSet {
            if  self.titleLabel != nil {
                self.titleLabel.text = titleText
            } else {
                NSLog("Could not set title text as label.text was nil : was trying to set to \(titleText)")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commitInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commitInit()
    }

    // Private

    func commitInit() {
        if self.subviews.count == 0 {
            print("Loading Nib")
            //let bundle = Bundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
            let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "gcCustomView", bundle: bundle)
            let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
            view.frame = bounds
            view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            addSubview(view)
        }
    }

}
```

(c) Main.storyboard Snapshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select `gcCustomView.xib` `File's Owner` change class name to `gcCustomerView`.

[image]

Right click on the `Label` drag from `outlet` to `File Owner`

[image]

Now It should look like this if you right click `Label`

[image]

I made a demo project. It is working ok. If you still have problem let me know. I'll upload my demo project in Github.

Comment: many thanks - this answer aligns the best to where I went wrong and documented how to correct things

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use xib make sure you have set your class name in **fileowner**

to do that first

[image]

Now add class name

[image]

And add **IBOutlet**

refer [Reuse a uiview xib in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335089/reuse-a-uiview-xib-in-storyboard)

Comment: I added the fileowner but this didn't help...I'll review the link you sent

Answer (score 2):

This is the memory issue.Label has no memory here. Therefore it returns 0 Instead of loading the nib in custom class you should load it in ViewController.
Replace your gcCustomView with the following code.

**gcCustomView.swift**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class gcCustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        if  self.titleLabel != nil {
            self.titleLabel.text = "Default"
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Could not set title text as label.text was nil : was trying to set to default")
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       // commitInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       // commitInit()
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.loadNib()

    }
    func loadNib() {
        let obj = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("gcCustomView", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as! gcCustomView
        obj.frame = (self.view.bounds)
        self.view.addSubview(obj)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Then build. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Keypath parameter in custom view and run.It's worked for me. :)